# Nestjs with prisma and Docker error in build

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, prisma

When I'm going to generate the docker container with nest, postgres and prisma I'm getting this error inside the container's shell, can anyone help me?
I don't know much about docker I got this code from this site https://www.tomray.dev/nestjs-docker-compose-postgres seems to work fine. I solved some errors since I'm on Mac m1

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path //package.json

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent 


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-04-12T19_06_44_722Z-debug-0.log
```

my docker file:

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:lts As development

# Required for Prisma Client to work in container
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies using the `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

RUN npm run prisma:generate

# Bundle app source
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Use the node user from the image (instead of the root user)
USER node

###################
# BUILD FOR PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:lts As build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# In order to run `npm run build` we need access to the Nest CLI.
# The Nest CLI is a dev dependency,
# In the previous development stage we ran `npm ci` which installed all dependencies.
# So we can copy over the node_modules directory from the development image into this build image.
COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Run the build command which creates the production bundle
RUN npm run build

# Set NODE_ENV environment variable
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Running `npm ci` removes the existing node_modules directory.
# Passing in --only=production ensures that only the production dependencies are installed.
# This ensures that the node_modules directory is as optimized as possible.
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps --only=production && npm cache clean --force

USER node

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:lts As production

# Copy the bundled code from the build stage to the production image
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

# Start the server using the production build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  api:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      target: production
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
    - .env
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}?schema=public
    command: npm run start:prod
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - docker-nest-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  docker-nest-postgres:
```